# improve run-length-encoding algorithm

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, encoding, run-length-encoding

I've got string interview question regarding run-length-encoding and my solution is O(n). Is there any way to improve it:

- input is AABBBCAAEE
- output suppose to be A2B3C1A2E2

```js
const firstString=(str)=>{
  const arr = str.split('');
  let counter = 1;
  let result ='';
  for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] === arr[i+1]){
      counter++;
    } else {
      result +=arr[i]+counter;
      counter = 1;
    }
  } return result
};
firstString('AABBBCAAEE');
```

Comment: check this: [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Comment: You have no choice but to look at each letter so I don't think you can do better than O(n).

Comment: Are you asking for ways to improve the big O time? Or are you also interested in ways to improve it in general (like making the code prettier and more concise)?

Comment: I was trying to see is there a way to improve in terms of Big O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using this approach with regex:** [Regex to match/group repeating characters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19683325/regex-to-match-group-repeating-characters-in-a-string)

**Regex explanation:** [`/((.)\2*)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/iSTHr8/1)

[image]

```js
var str = 'AABBBCAAEE';
var result = str.replace(/((.)\2*)/g, function(match) {
  var [letter] = match;
  return `${letter}${match.length}`;
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Would you happen to know the time complexity of this? Is it still O(n)?

Comment: @0x499602D2 yes it's O(n) because depends of the String's length. This approach is fancier instead of an improvement in terms of complexity.

Comment: I was trying to see is there a way to improve in terms of Big O, but looks like it is impossible, and that solution looks more elegant

Answer (score 2):

One way that you can improve this is to not perform the split. Strings are also indexable:

```
let firstString = (str) => {
  if (str.length <= 0) {
    return "";
  }
  const result = [];
  result.push(str[0]);
  let counter = 1;
  for (let i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (result[result.length - 1] === str[i]) {
      counter++;
    } else {
      result.push(counter, str[i]);
      counter = 1;
    }
  }
  result.push(counter);
  return result.join("");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is [**run-length encoding**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).

There are quite a few of [existing Javascript implementations](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding#JavaScript) for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Python Implementation
Time - O(n), Space - O(n)

```py
def encode(_str):
    n = len(_str)

    if _str == _str[0] * n:
        return f'{n}{_str[0]}'

    i, _count = 1, 1
    encoding = ''

    while i < n:
        if _str[i] == _str[i-1]:
            _count += 1
        else:
            encoding += f'{_count}{_str[i-1]}'
            _count = 1

        i += 1

    encoding += f'{_count}{_str[i-1]}'  # last iteration

    return encoding


assert encode('WWWWWW') == '6W'
assert encode('WWWWWWWWWBBBBBBB') == '9W7B'
assert encode('WWWWWWWWWBBBBBBBR') == '9W7B1R'
assert encode('W') == '1W'
```